# ZF2 run command to create controllers, actions, forms,

Tags: php, forms, controller, zend-framework2

I'm trying to make the switch from Zend Framework 1.12 to 2.1.4 and I'm having a hard time with it. I code in Netbeans IDE and am used to 'Run Zend Command' (by clicking with the right mouse button on the project name and then Zend > Run Command) for creating new controllers, forms, actions, etc... but I can't seem to find the same functionality with ZF2? What's the right way to create new actions, controllers or forms?

Comment: Try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414282/step-by-step-migration-from-zend-framework-1-to-2

Thanks

Comment: Also, did you check ZFTool? (https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool)