# upgrade Zend Framework 1.12 to 2.3

Tags: linux, zend-framework, zend-framework2, upgrade, centos6

i've got zend framework 1.12.5 on my CentOS6 server. but i'd like to upgrade to be Zend Framework 2.3. How can i upgrade it or i have to remove zf1 off first and reinstalling zf2 instead of upgrade?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate [Step by step migration from Zend Framework 1 to 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414282/step-by-step-migration-from-zend-framework-1-to-2)

Answer (score 1):

No buddy, You can't simply upgrade ZF1 to ZF2. In case you need you move to ZF2 be sure that ZF2 is not just an upper version of ZF1 but the whole Architecture is also changed.

So, If you really need to move then 
1. Firstly you will need to remove ZF1 library completely.
2. Install ZF2 package.
3. Now make changes in your code to work accordingly with ZF2 as most of the things will stop working once to move to ZF2.

However, I would suggest don't migrate to ZF2 just for the sake of upgrading, migrate only if you dont have any other choice. As this is a very painful task.

have a good luck.

Comment: i actually haven't work on it yet. after i install ZF1 i realize that i make mistake, 
i was wanted to install zf2. so now i need just remove the whole zf1 of i think it's better way. But how can i remove it ?

Comment: Ahh!! OK then you can do a fresh install instead.

Comment: yeah i am very newbie of Zend Framework, starting today and mess my server up hahaha!! 

how can i remove ZF1 by the way?

Comment: just find the folder where you installed zf1 and delete the files. If on linux server: rm -rf PATHTO ZF1 will do