# Protected variables on zend framework db

Tags: zend-framework, php-7, zend-db

I want to be able to seperate my database tables, as i dont want the table getting too big.

when a company registers on my website i would like them to use there own db space.. so in zend i have my model file that connects to db but it will not allow me to make it dynamic. please could some one help me..

[db model file to connect to departments that belong to a company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbPCh.png)

```
public function company_id(){
  $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
  $company_id = $auth->getIdentity()->comp;
  return $company_id;
}

protected $_comp = $this->company_id();
//$name = '2_departments';
protected $_name = $this->_comp."_departments";
protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_Department';
```

when i use the above code it crashes without error. But if manually code it in and create a php file for every db table it will work file.

[manual entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl2Up.png)

```
protected $_name = "2_departments";
protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_Department';
```

if someone could assign that would be awesome.

I have another example

Main class

class Application_Model_Table_Departments extends Teabag_Db_Table
{

```
 public function fetchdepartments() {
       $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
       $company_id = $auth->getIdentity()->comp;

       $select = $this->select()
                      ->from(array('deps'=>$this->_name), array('*'))
                      ->where('deps.is_deleted = 0');

       return $this->fetchAll($select);
   }
```

}

but then ive extented the class with two other files
custom1department.php
custom2department.php

class Application_Model_Table_Custom1Departments extends Application_Model_Table_Departments
{

```
protected $_name = "1_departments";
protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_Department';
```

}

and

class Application_Model_Table_Custom2Departments extends Application_Model_Table_Departments
{

```
protected $_name = "2_departments";
protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_Department';
```

}

any ideas on how to make a class dynamic and the class name dynamic?

Comment: Please post the code and not images of code.

Comment: Sorry give me a min

Comment: Are you still using Zend-Framework version1? ("Zend_Auth" seems to be ZF1.) This could be the reason, your code is not working, when using PHP7. Besides: This would be high safety hazard if you were still using ZF1, as it has reached its EOL long ago.

Comment: Oh crap, is they an easy way to update to a newer zend?

Comment: Migration can be quite a hassle. If possible, I recommend starting a new ZF3-Application all together and just try to transfer some of your own code manually. Starting a [new ZF3-App](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/overview/) is easy and straight forward. If you decide you still want to migrate your whole ZF1-Application: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17329180/514962) might be of help. However, this is a guide on how to migrate ZF1 to ZF2. Currently, ZF3 is the newest version and should be used.

Comment: You may consider having a company_id field in a departments table to keep track of each company's department. That way, you will not need any dynamic table-generation functionality. Also, you should try to pass the company_id as an argument to the method/function rather than getting an instance of zend-auth just so as to get the company-id of the logged-in persona.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider having a company_id field in a departments table to keep track of each company's department. That way, you will not need any dynamic table-generation functionality.

Also, you should try to pass the company_id as an argument to the method/function rather than getting an instance of zend-auth just so as to get the company-id of the logged-in persona.